# Передача enum'а в конструктор класса

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня есть класс, в конструктор которого я хочу передать параметры в виде `enum`.

```
class PressureValue
{
public:
    enum pressureMeasureUnit {puUnknown, puAuto, puAtmosphere, puTechAtmosphere,
                              puKgCm2, puPascal, puMillimetreOfMercury, puTor, puMillibar}pressureMeasureUnitP;
    PressureValue(PressureValue::pressureMeasureUnit defaultUnit = puKgCm2){
        defaultPressureUnit = defaultUnit;
    }
    ~PressureValue(){}
    float value = 0.0;
    //перегрузка оператора
    PressureValue& operator=(float f){
        value = f;
        return *this;
    }
    operator float() const{
        return value;
    }
private:
    pressureMeasureUnit defaultPressureUnit;
    pressureMeasureUnit convertingUnit;
};

class PressureDrop
{

private:
    PressureValue declinePressure, declinePressureUp, declinePressureDown, declinePressureDelta;
    //PressureValue environmentPressure;
    PressureValue environmentPressure(PressureValue::puMillimetreOfMercury);
    int declinePressureTime, environmentTemperature;
public:
    PressureDrop(){}
    ~PressureDrop(){}

};
int main(){
    PressureValue p(PressureValue::puMillibar);
}
```

Если это делать действительно в `main`, то все хорошо. А если я хочу создать экземпляр класса `PressureValue` в виде `private`-поля какого-то класса, то получаю ошибку:

> ошибка: 'PressureValue::puMillimetreOfMercury' is not a type

Как-то можно выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: @VTT исправил код. И я написал, что в `main` все хорошо. а в полях класса не очень

Comment: @VTT спасибо, убрал. В оригинале он наследуются от другого класса. Не заметил, когда упрощал код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, вы пытаетесь сделать инициализацию поля `environmentPressure` при объявлении (а не объявить функцию). Для этого следует использовать [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
PressureValue environmentPressure{PressureValue::puMillimetreOfMercury};
```

С переходом на С++11 list initialization следует использовать вообще всегда.

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли.Век живи - век учись, вообще впервые такое вижу. Спасибо большое за объяснение!